# How do you align a system of equations when one line is longer than the others?

Tags: latex, mathjax

I'm trying to align this system of equations nicely but it doesn't work out. I think I could hack it but I keep running into this problem and would like to do it right. [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t17k87v2/)

[image]

```
\begin{align}
    a_{11}x_1  + a_{12}x_2  + a_{13}x_3 + \cdots + a_{1n}x_n &= 0 \\
    a_{21}x_1  + a_{22}x_2  + a_{23}x_3 + \cdots + a_{2n}x_n &= 0 \\
    a_{31}x_1  + a_{32}x_2  + a_{33}x_3 + \cdots + a_{3n}x_n &= 0 \\
    &\vdots \\
    a_{m1}x_1  + a_{m2}x_2  + a_{m3}x_3 + \cdots + a_{mn}x_n &= 0
\end{align}
```

Comment: By aligning it, you're referring to the terms and operators that you want horizontally aligned, correct?

Comment: well the terms and operators on each row should be horizontally aligned with the terms and operators on the others rows. so yes, correct.

Comment: What about [this](https://jsfiddle.net/dpbaom3e/)?

Comment: that's pretty nice. serious question, where did you learn how to do that?

Comment: [I](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/5764/werner) contribute to [tex.se]. However, MathJax is different from (La)TeX, so things might not be as straight-forward.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set this in a single `align` and adjust for the spacing using some `\phantom`s and over`lap`ping:

[image]

```
\begin{align}
  \phantom{a_{m1}x_1}\llap{a_{11}x_1\,} + 
    \phantom{a_{m2}x_2}\llap{a_{12}x_2\,} + 
    \phantom{a_{m3}x_3}\llap{a_{13}x_3\,} + \cdots + 
    \phantom{a_{mn}x_n}\llap{a_{1n}x_n\,} &= 0 \\
  \phantom{a_{m1}x_1}\llap{a_{21}x_1\,} + 
    \phantom{a_{m2}x_2}\llap{a_{22}x_2\,} + 
    \phantom{a_{m3}x_3}\llap{a_{23}x_3\,} + \cdots + 
    \phantom{a_{mn}x_n}\llap{a_{2n}x_n\,} &= 0 \\
  \phantom{a_{m1}x_1}\llap{a_{31}x_1\,} + 
    \phantom{a_{m2}x_2}\llap{a_{32}x_2\,} + 
    \phantom{a_{m3}x_3}\llap{a_{33}x_3\,} + \cdots + 
    \phantom{a_{mn}x_n}\llap{a_{3n}x_n\,} &= 0 \\
  & \phantom{{}={}}\llap{\vdots~~} \\
  a_{m1}x_1 + a_{m2}x_2 + a_{m3}x_3 + \cdots + a_{mn}x_n &= 0
\end{align}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dpbaom3e/4/)

`\phantom{<stuff>}` sets `<stuff>` in an invisible box thereby taking up the space of `<stuff>` (horizontally and vertically) without setting anything visually. `\llap{<stuff>}` puts `<stuff>` in a zero-width box that is right-aligned. This effectively lets `<stuff>` hang or over`lap` to the `l`eft.

Additional alignment tweaks are made possible by `\,` - a small horizontal space.

Answer (score 1):

In `align` and similar environments, vertical alignment is performed along the `&` characters in each line. So, if you want to align along each `+` sign, equip them with `&` each:

EDIT: Since `align` centers the rows, you need to surround the `+` with `&` on *both sides*:

```
\begin{align}
    a_{11}x_1  &+& a_{12}x_2  &+& a_{13}x_3 &+& \cdots &+& a_{1n}x_n &=& 0 \\
    a_{21}x_1  &+& a_{22}x_2  &+& a_{23}x_3 &+& \cdots &+& a_{2n}x_n &=& 0 \\
    a_{31}x_1  &+& a_{32}x_2  &+& a_{33}x_3 &+& \cdots &+& a_{3n}x_n &=& 0 \\
    &&&&&&&&&\vdots \\
    a_{m1}x_1  &+& a_{m2}x_2  &+& a_{m3}x_3 &+& \cdots &+& a_{mn}x_n &=& 0
\end{align}
```

Alternatively, you could use `\[\begin{array}{lllll}...\end{array}\]` as an environment, left-aligning the individual columns.

Comment: I thought that was was how you do it but that doesn't work for some reason. It doesn't even vertically align them. https://imgur.com/a/dsTu3